# Moment in angular not displaying correct format

Tags: angular, momentjs

On my project, i am using moment to parse the format shown on the datepicker. When running without enabling production mode, the format is shown as intended.
[Without Production mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3jzs.png)

But when running with production mode enabled, the format is not working.
[Production Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zI5p.png)

Is there anyone know why is this happening? and is there any suggestion to fix it?

Here is the code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

import * as _moment from 'moment';
const moment = _moment;

export var MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-date',
  templateUrl: './custom-date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-date.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class CustomDateComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() myFormControl: FormControl;
    @Input() myFormGroup: FormGroup;
    @Input() myFormControlName: string;
    @Input() myName: string;
    @Input() myFormat: string;
  @Input() myDisabled: boolean;
  @Input() minDate = new Date(1900,0,1);
  @Input() maxDate = new Date(2200,0,1);
  @Output() myDateChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    MY_FORMATS.display.dateInput = this.myFormat;
  }
  changeDate(): void{
    this.myDateChange.emit(this.myFormGroup.get(this.myFormControlName).value);
  }
}
```

Comment: would be good if you can add code here.

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal code added.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly define the format you want.

```
let momentPeriodStr = momentDateObj.format('YYYY/MM');
let momentDateStr = momentDateObj.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```